# Как программно определить дату последнего обновления OC Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как программно определить дату последнего обновления OC Android?

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/9297131 попробуйте как-то так https://rextester.com/NKZ51203

Comment: Оказалось всё просто - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545674/how-to-determine-the-security-patch-level-of-an-android-device